# How to display a list of check box items one per line

Tags: php

I have a list of items that a user can select from when listing their house. I then display these on the frontend using the following:

```
<? if($group[property_amenities] != "") { ?>
    <hr>
    <h2 class="vmargin">Amenities</h2>
    <?php echo $group[property_amenities]; ?>
<? } ?>
```

The issues is that I believe I don't have access to change the HTML and the items are listed as follows:

Amenities

Open Plan,Carpeted Floors,

How can I modify the above code to display the items in separate rows, as well as remove the "," or replace the "," with something like " - "

Comment: Since there are no `,` in the code, I assume `$group[property_amenities]` is already equals to the whole string `Open Plan,Carpeted Floors,`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all the commas with break tags, or dashes, or whatever you want.

```
<?php echo str_replace(',', '<br>', $group[property_amenities];) ?>
```